# Show that invertible elements of the algebraic closure of $F_p$ is not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I want to show that invertible elements of the algebraic closure of $F_p$ is not cyclic, where p is a prime. I know that the algebraic closure of $F_p$ is countably infinite, since it is equal to the union of all $F_{p^{n!}}$  for all natural numbers N.

My proof is that if invertible elements of the algebraic closure of $F_p$ is cyclic, then we have a generator f. By definition, f is an element of $F_{p^{i!}}$, for a particular i in N. This means that the group generated by f has order ${p^{i!}-1}$, which is finite, so we have a contradiction.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Incidentally, you can just write $i$ instead of $i!$, though both are correct.